# How to display HTTP file download progress while reading from racket input-port

Tags: http, download, progress-bar, lisp, racket

The root of my problem is that I need to be able to get the total number of bytes that have been downloaded to display a progress bar as part of a cli tool.

I'm downloading a file through an HTTP GET request. Using the "Content-Length" http header I can see the total size of the file I will be downloading with my client. I figured I would then just do the old **"downloaded / total = progress"** formula.

My current implementation can fetch the file and write it to the local filesystem no problem so the setup of the request and ports works as expected, I really just need some guidance on how one would get some insight into what the input port is actually doing (events?) I'm very new to Racket.

I'm using the the following library for making the http requests:

https://docs.racket-lang.org/http/index.html?q=http

There is mention of helpful procedure assisting in the implementation of a progress bar:

https://github.com/greghendershott/http/blob/master/http/request.rkt#L505

Here's what I have so far:

```
#| Basically just for debugging/testing, receives the default input-port 
#| and headers from the call/input-request procedure

(define (handle-entity in headers)
  (display headers)

  #| looking at the source this "read-entity/transfer-decoding-port" 
  #| should be useful for what I want to do
  (define decoded-port (read-entity/transfer-decoding-port in headers))

  #| writing the file works as expected, what I really want to do is
  #| is get the download progress as I write to the output-port
  (call-with-output-file "test.tar.gz"
                        (lambda (out)
                          (display (port->bytes decoded-port) out))))

(define (fetch)
  (call/input-request "1.1"
                      "GET"                       
                      "https://example.com/test.tar.gz"
                      empty
                      handle-entity #| will handle the input port created in this procedure
                      #:redirects 10))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`port-progress-evt`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Input.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._port-progress-evt%29%29) to efficiently wait until a port has been read from, and you can use [`port-next-location`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/linecol.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._port-next-location%29%29) to check how many bytes have been read so far. You can do this in a loop on another thread to update a progress bar asynchronously. For example:

```
(define (listen-for-progress in)
  (sync (port-progress-evt in))
  (unless (port-closed? in)
    (define-values [line col pos] (port-next-location in))
    (printf "bytes read: ~a\n" pos)
    (listen-for-progress in)))

(define (read-with-progress in)
  (thread (λ () (listen-for-progress in)))
  #| do something with in |#)
```

As an aside, you should use [`copy-port`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-lib.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fport..rkt%29._copy-port%29%29) instead of `port->bytes` followed by `display`, since `copy-port` will stream the input port into the output port, but 
`port->bytes` will read the whole port into memory before it starts writing to the output port.